# Azure Devops how to list all the pipeline variables in a task

Tags: azure-devops

How to get all the pipeline variables(queue time variables) in a step?

```
steps:
- bash: |
    az pipelines variable list --pipeline-id $(System.DefinitionId)
  displayName: 'Show build list varibales'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

The above task only prints the following. Doesn't print the values that I have entered at runtime.If the pipeline variables have default then it prints the value.

```
 "pipelineVariable": {
    "allowOverride": true,
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": ""
  }
```

Comment: variables or parameters?

Comment: variables. I want to read them all at once loop through and create an object(array/json) and pass them to a template.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for an answer. Queue time variables can be accessed as env(bash) and Get-ChildItem env:*(pwsh). You just need to filter them because these commands are going to show all system/process/user defined environment variables.